# How to resolve a dependency in an external package workspace_file?

Tags: bazel

Trying to use a target in the `build_file` from an external package imported through `http_archive` that has dependencies defined in the external package workspace via the `workspace_file` attribute fails. I'm using Bazel 0.27.0 on Debian Testing.

The documentation only talks about referencing targets in the provided `build_file`, but I could not find any information how one could reference a dependency defined in the provided `workspace_file` in the provided `build_file`.

The usual `@stringtemplate3//jar` syntax fails, but I don't know how I could include a reference to the imported archive which according to the manual would have to start with `@antlr3_runtimes`.

The project layout looks like this:

```
├── antlr.BUILD
├── antlr.WORKSPACE
├── BUILD
├── external_dependency
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── bazel
│                   ├── BUILD
│                   └── Hello.java
├── LICENSE
└── WORKSPACE
```

The `WORKSPACE` definition looks like this:

```py
workspace(name="bazel")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "antlr3_runtimes",
    sha256 = "d4f7d3c38c5523f8009ff37528e5797c81adb454be6acc9af507cfcb41f2016f",
    strip_prefix = "antlr3-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3/archive/master.tar.gz"],
    build_file = "@//:antlr.BUILD",
    workspace_file = "@//:antlr.WORKSPACE",
)
```

It seems that the provided `workspace_file` is not even analyzed. The build already fails when it tries to resolve the dependencies in the custom build file.

A repro can be found here: https://github.com/marcohu/bazel

`bazel build //...` shows this error message:

```
ERROR: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/64492308e78c9898c41f12c18dd29b63/external/antlr3_runtimes/BUILD.bazel:43:1: no such package '@stringtemplate3//jar': The repository '@stringtemplate3' could not be resolved and referenced by '@antlr3_runtimes//:antlr3_tool'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//external_dependency/src/main/java/bazel:hello' failed; build aborted: no such package '@stringtemplate3//jar': The repository '@stringtemplate3' could not be resolved
```

I reported this in the Bazel issue tracker, but it got rejected with a hint to post here.

Is this use case something that is just not possible? Or did I got the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as of now (I suppose this statement may change in the future versions), bazel does not directly support transitive external dependencies. `WORKSPACE` file would still get read in even in your case and if it contained entirely broken syntax it'd still fail, but it does not get "acted upon" and you could (currently) for instance load from non-existing labels or call undefined functions and would still be left none the wiser for a nested `WORKSPACE`.

You essentially have two options:

1. Repeat your nested dependencies (`http_archive` rules) in your "parent"/top `WORKSPACE`.
2. You can define a function(s) with corresponding repository rules that you load and call in your "parent"/top `WORKSPACE`.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the `http_archive` workspace could act independently, but sadly it seems this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Bazel actually does support the transitive fetching of jvm dependencies. https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external

**WORKSPACE**

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

rules_jvm_external_tag = "2.0.1"

rules_jvm_external_sha = "55e8d3951647ae3dffde22b4f7f8dee11b3f70f3f89424713debd7076197eaca"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    sha256 = rules_jvm_external_sha,
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % rules_jvm_external_tag,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % rules_jvm_external_tag,
)

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    name = "maven",
    artifacts = [
        "io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.22.1",
        "io.grpc:grpc-api:1.22.1",
        "io.grpc:grpc-testing:1.22.1",
        "io.grpc:grpc-core:1.22.1",
        "junit:junit:4.12",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com/",
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
)
```

**BUILD**

```
...
java_library(
    name = "hyphenation-service",
    srcs = ["src/test/java/com/example/hyphenation/HyphenationServiceTest.java"],
    deps = ["@maven//:io_grpc_grpc_core"]
)
...
```

Example repository https://github.com/mancini0/bazel-grpc-playground

Comment: It's the case of point 2., you can do that with (custom) functions / rules, it however is not the same thing as transitive dependencies across external dependencies which as of now are not supported.